# Python3: Value not printing

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm in the middle of an exercise to translate DNA into protein. I've got a dictionary "codons" that I want to iterate through and match keys to elements in a list "plist." And then, of course, print the value only to a new element ("protein") that I'll concatenate later, once I get this working :P.

My problem is that the code after the dictionary doesn't print anything, though it doesn't throw an error either. I've tried adding a return statement to see if that would fix it but nah. Hints/guidance/halp? Am I going about this pythonically?

```
n=3
protein = []
plist = [DNA_input[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(DNA_input), n)]
if len(plist[-1]) % 3 == 0:
    print("Sequence length OK")
else:
    print("Taking a bit off the end...")
    plist.pop()
    print(plist)
codons = {
'ATA':'I', 'ATC':'I', 'ATT':'I', 'ATG':'M',
'ACA':'T', 'ACC':'T', 'ACG':'T', 'ACT':'T',
'AAC':'N', 'AAT':'N', 'AAA':'K', 'AAG':'K',
'AGC':'S', 'AGT':'S', 'AGA':'R', 'AGG':'R',
'CTA':'L', 'CTC':'L', 'CTG':'L', 'CTT':'L',
'CCA':'P', 'CCC':'P', 'CCG':'P', 'CCT':'P',
'CAC':'H', 'CAT':'H', 'CAA':'Q', 'CAG':'Q',
'CGA':'R', 'CGC':'R', 'CGG':'R', 'CGT':'R',
'GTA':'V', 'GTC':'V', 'GTG':'V', 'GTT':'V',
'GCA':'A', 'GCC':'A', 'GCG':'A', 'GCT':'A',
'GAC':'D', 'GAT':'D', 'GAA':'E', 'GAG':'E',
'GGA':'G', 'GGC':'G', 'GGG':'G', 'GGT':'G',
'TCA':'S', 'TCC':'S', 'TCG':'S', 'TCT':'S',
'TTC':'F', 'TTT':'F', 'TTA':'L', 'TTG':'L',
'TAC':'Y', 'TAT':'Y', 'TAA':'_', 'TAG':'_',
'TGC':'C', 'TGT':'C', 'TGA':'_', 'TGG':'W',
}

for key, value in codons.items():
    if key in codons in plist:
            return value
            protein.append(value)
            print(protein)
```

Comment: `if key in codons in plist` - that's a new one for me, what's that meant to do?

Comment: I figured that one might be a source of trouble, too -- if a codon key equals a value in plist, then [do stuff].

Comment: given you already know key is in codons then you can just do `if key in plist:` and move the `return` statement after the `print`

Comment: That did it! Thanks AChampion!

Answer (score 2):

You're bailing out on the line:

```
return value
```

the program never reaches the line `print(protein)`

In addition to that, most chances are that in the following line:

```
if key in codons in plist:
```

you're not doing what you think you're doing.

Since you posted only part of the original code, it's not easy to debug it. You should look at the full error (stacktrace), which line generates it and go from there.

Comment: Not to mention that in the provided code it's actually a syntax error.

Comment: I thought so earlier, but I removed it and still don't get anything printed from that part of the code.

Comment: Surprisingly `if key in codons in plist:` isn't a syntax error.  Just defining `DNA_input='ACDGATCB'` it runs fine - though not producing the expected output.

Comment: Yes, but getting the string split into triplet codons isn't the problem. I want to get the protein sequence as a result. That's where I'm having trouble.

Comment: I think you just need `if key in plist:`

Comment: @jswalker you should post an example `DNA_input` otherwise it's impossible to debug your code. Further, if the script crashes - why don't you post the stacktrace ?

Comment: Issue solved, but it didn't crash - just didn't produce the desired output. Thanks though!